# Creating a Trigger in MySQL that stores stock levels once a sale takes place

Tags: mysql

I have a basic database for a retail store with 4 tables, one of which stores Order info, one that stores Product info and one that stores Supplier info.

I  am trying to run a query that will display total sum of stock sold figure (in dollars) with a GROUP BY supplier with ROLL UP. I have a feeling that SUM should be in the code but I can't find where to put it, so far I have this:

```
SELECT ORDERS.OrderPrice, PRODUCT.SupplierID, SUPPLIER.SupplierName
FROM ((ORDERS
INNER JOIN PRODUCT ON ORDERS.ProductID = PRODUCT.ProductID)
INNER JOIN SUPPLIER ON PRODUCT.SupplierID = SUPPLIER.SupplierID)
GROUP BY SupplierName WITH ROLLUP;
```

The database can be viewed on DB Fiddle here:

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qS515ShyFGxgj4h6Ga6HA3/1#&togetherjs=aNgE8G0yMh

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Your fiddle have an error. What's that on line 107 ?

Comment: `SUM(ORDERS.OrderPrice)` that should do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You must use SUM function with orderPrice

```
SELECT SUM(ORDERS.OrderPrice), SUPPLIER.SupplierName FROM ((ORDERS INNER JOIN PRODUCT ON ORDERS.ProductID = PRODUCT.ProductID) INNER JOIN SUPPLIER ON PRODUCT.SupplierID = SUPPLIER.SupplierID) GROUP BY SupplierName with ROLLUP
```